# Bulleted list or numbered list is not highlighted vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I using in vba-word.
I try to select with the curser line to macro.
The line contain Bulleted list or numbered list and when it's send to macro, all the content sending exept number or bulleted or character, and i need it in the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString